# React client-side rendered components - state doesn't update while script is still running

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't have a reproducible example for this but basically what I'm doing is this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let that = this;
    fetch(...).then((response) => {
      response.json().then((data) => that.setState(data);)
      window.setTimeout(that.tick.bind(that), 1000);
    });
  }

  tick() {
    /* do some calculation to update the state */
    let state = {...};
    this.setState(state);
    console.log("Set state: ", state);
    if (someCondition)
      window.setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Render state: ", this.state);
    return ( ... react output ... );
  }
}
```

I fetch some data, add it to the state, then start a timer that calls `tick()` once per second.  `tick()` updates the state, logs the new state (note - the value I'm setting not the value of `this.state`) and then decides whether to set a new timer.  `render()` logs what its idea of the state is and then returns the rendered content.

This all works.  I can see in the console the state value I'm setting and then `render()`'s idea of the state being the same as that value I've just set.

The problem comes when I run it all through webpack to create a single JS bundle.  Then `setState()` stops doing what I expect.  I can still see the value that I'm feeding to `setState()` but the state value seen by `render()` is `{}` until I stop setting new timers.  **Then** the state value seen by `render()` updates and the content renders correctly.

The output of webpack is pretty impenetrable so I'm having a bit of trouble tracking down what has changed to cause this difference in behaviour.  Is this a well-known gotcha?

I'm aware that `setState()` is not guaranteed to be synchronous and that I shouldn't expect the value of `this.state` to update immediately - but I did expect it would at least have updated by the time `render()` is next called.

Comment: How did you verify that it's when you stop setting new timers that things stabilize?  Are you validating that you have a response from the endpoint you've requested well before stabilization?

Comment: @tbhesswebber Yes, I'm logging out the response from the endpoint and it's correct.  The ticks go on for about 20s and it's clearly when they stop that the render happens correctly - I can see on the console that the state logged in the `render()` function only changes on the last tick.

Comment: @Tom I tried to reproduce your code in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-playground-forked-h8x6lr?file=/src/App.js), can you check and let me know if that's the same? Issue isn't reproduced FYI.

Comment: My apologies @HirenF - this was my bad, though in a somewhat interesting way.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be just me assuming that `this.state` got updated as soon as I called `this.setState()`.  The webpack confusion came in because the minification changed React's decision about how to optimise state updates - unminified, it updated the state immediately and so multiple state updates to different fields in the same cycle were okay.  Once it was minified, it deferred state updates and so multiple state updates to different fields ended up losing the earlier updates.